# Radio button dinâmico não fica checked com angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho um radio button que é exibido dinamicamente de acordo com o json abaixo:

```
    {
    "cd_pauta": 64,
    "nr_numeracao": 10,
    "cd_subtipo_pauta_periodo_letivo": 1,
    "ds_observacao": "Mbappe > que Neymar?",
    "sg_conteudo": "trt",
    "pauta_conteudo": "Mbappe > que Neymar? (Teste cabuloso)",
    "grau": [
        {
            "cd_grau_atitudinal": 2,
            "nm_grau_atitudinal": "BOM",
            "sg_grau_atitudinal": "B",
            "vl_grau_atitudinal": "0",
            "cd_configuracao_grau_periodo_letivo": 2
        },
        {
            "cd_grau_atitudinal": 3,
            "nm_grau_atitudinal": "RUIM",
            "sg_grau_atitudinal": "R",
            "vl_grau_atitudinal": "24",
            "cd_configuracao_grau_periodo_letivo": 3,
            "checked": true,
        },
        {
            "cd_grau_atitudinal": 1,
            "nm_grau_atitudinal": "MUITO BOM",
            "sg_grau_atitudinal": "MB",
            "vl_grau_atitudinal": "100000",
            "cd_configuracao_grau_periodo_letivo": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

E de acordo com o que estiver no banco, meu backend concatena a uma determinada posição do objeto o valor "checked": true.

No frontend eu pego esse array de objetos e monto um formulario de perguntas e respostas. Se determinada pergunta estiver sido respondida o grau retornara com o valor "checked": true presente.

```
*ngFor="let pauta of pautas; let i = index;">
  <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="15%"  fxFlexOrder="1" class="conteudo-pauta">{{pauta.nr_numeracao}}</div>
  <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="30%" fxFlexOrder="2" class="conteudo-pauta">{{pauta.pauta_conteudo}}</div>
  <div class="item item-3" fxFlex  fxFlexOrder="3" class="conteudo-pauta">
    <div class="alinhar-grau">
      <div *ngFor="let grau of pauta.grau; let j = index;" class="graus">
        <input 
        [(ngModel)]="options[pauta.cd_subtipo_pauta_periodo_letivo]"
        value="{{pauta.cd_subtipo_pauta_periodo_letivo}}-{{grau.cd_grau_atitudinal}}"
        name="option{{pauta.cd_subtipo_pauta_periodo_letivo}}"
        [attr.checked]="grau.checked === true ? 'checked' : ' ' "
        type="radio"
        /> {{grau.sg_grau_atitudinal}}
          <div>
            -> {{options[pauta.cd_subtipo_pauta_periodo_letivo]}}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O problema é que independente do status o radio nunca vem preenchido. Reparei que ao remover o ngModel onde tem "checked": true passa a ser preenchido, porem ao submeter o formulário, eu perco a referência q preciso para persistir.
Tem alguma forma que eu consiga preencher o radio dinamico e nao perder a posição da lista?

[image: Exemplo da lista]

Deve ficar assim, porem o valor ruim era pra vir preenchido.

Comment: vc ta usando ngModel define qual vc quer que fique marcado alterando o valor do ngModel para o que vc deseja.